# AS3 Error 1120, after extending a class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class

I don't how to describe the situation in short, so I am going to describe it in details.

I have created a class, extended from MovieClip. It looks like this:

```
    // Libraries are imported

    public class WindowObject extends MovieClip {
        public function WindowObject():void {
            dragArea_mc.addEventListener(...);
        }

        public function AFunction():void {
            if(close_mc == null) {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }
```

Where dragArea_mc is (or should be) defined in the MovieClips that use this as the base class.

I have created a MovieClip, with two children MovieClips named as dragArea_mc and close_mc, and set its base class to be the one on top. It worked fine. No problem at all.

Since different windows have different behaviors, I wanted to create some other classes based on WindowObject. (i.e. they extends WindowObject, and have additional functions.)

I changed the base class of the MovieClip created in step 2 to be the new class. Now, here is the problem:

```
    1120: Access of undefined property dragArea_mc.
    1120: Access of undefined property close_mc.
```

When I clicked on the errors, they redirected me to the WindowObject class.

If I don't create new classes, but just write the additional functions on the MovieClip directly, and set back the base class to be WindowObject, it works fine again.

Comment: try defining you class as `public dynamic class`

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tried to change `public class WindowObject` to 'public dynamic class WindowObject', but it still has the same errors.

Comment: In addition, I also added 'dynamic' in the new classes, it cannot fix the problem.

Comment: The constructor WindowObject() should not be defined as returning void (it can be regarded as a function that returns an instance of the object, although it is not declared as returning anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just fired up flash cs5, and reproduced your issue. And I have to admit I am a bit puzzled... And I'm going to have to investigate a little more, because I'm not sure I really understand what is going on.

Try setting both classes to `public dynamic class...`

and then instead of referencing `dragArea_mc` directly, reference it through `this.dragArea_mc`

what I ended up having:

```
public dynamic class TestParent extends MovieClip {
    public function TestParent() {
        // trace(drag_mc); doesn't work
        trace(this.drag_mc); // works as long as the class is dynamic
    }
}

public dynamic class TestChild extends TestParent {
    public function TestChild() {
        // trace(drag_mc); surprisingly does work, but odd it doesn't work in the parent.
        trace(this.drag_mc); // works as long as the class (and its parent) are dynamic
    }
}
```

And then in the UI, created a new MovieClip and set its base class to `TestChild` and created a child movieclip with an instance name of `drag_me`.

... I'm going to investigate more, and edit this post later, but try that and see if it helps fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for help! So, what I need is adding "dynamic", and also "this." It works fine now. Cheers!

Comment: It is interesting that I have been told don't use "this." if possible because it will affect performance. But, this time, "this." is needed. orz

Answer (score -1):

it may be undefined because it isn't on the stage quite yet..try it like this

```
// Libraries are imported

class WindowObject extends MovieClip {
    public function WindowObject():void {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        dragArea_mc.addEventListener(...);
    }

    public function AFunction():void {
        if(close_mc == null) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thinks to quick response. But I think it is not the problem, because it also says that close_mc is undefined.

Comment: @Ronnie A `DisplayObject` instance doesn't have to be on the stage to be existent...